# Getting MS PowerBI error when reading hive table through MapR drill odbc driver

Tags: hive, powerbi

I'm getting this error when trying to read data from hive table through MapR Drill ODBC Driver into Microsoft PowerBI Desktop tool : -

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MapR][Drill] (1040) Drill failed to execute the query: 
from `hive.database`.`demo_table`
[30027]Query execution error. Details:[ 
PARSE ERROR: Encountered "from" at line 2, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "ALTER" ...
    "SET" ...
    "RESET" ...
    "WITH" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "TRUE" ...
    "FALSE" ...
    "UNKNOWN" ...
    "NULL" ...
    <LBRACE_D> ...
    <LBRACE_T> ...
    <LBRACE_TS> ...
    "DATE" ...
    "TIME" ...
    "TIMESTAMP" ...
    "INTERVAL" ...
    "?" ...
    "CAST" ...
    "EXTRACT" ...
    "POSITION" ...
    "CONVERT" ...
    "TRANSLATE" ...
    "OVERLAY" ...
    "FLOOR" ...
    "CEIL" ...
    "CEILING" ...
    "SUBSTRING" ...
    "TRIM" ...
    <LBRACE_FN> ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "ARRAY" ...
    "SPECIFIC" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    "ABS" ...
    "AVG" ...
    "CARDINALITY" ...
    "CHAR_LENGTH" ...
    "CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
    "COALESCE" ...
    "COLLECT" ...
    "COVAR_POP" ...
    "COVAR_SAMP" ...
    "CUME_DIST" ...
    "COUNT" ...
    "CURRENT_DATE" ...
    "CURRENT_TIME" ...
    "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
    "DENSE_RANK" ...
    "ELEMENT" ...
    "EXP" ...
    "FIRST_VALUE" ...
    "FUSION" ...
    "GROUPING" ...
    "LAST_VALUE" ...
    "LN" ...
    "LOCALTIME" ...
    "LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
    "LOWER" ...
    "MAX" ...
    "MIN" ...
    "MOD" ...
    "NULLIF" ...
    "OCTET_LENGTH" ...
    "PERCENT_RANK" ...
    "POWER" ...
    "RANK" ...
    "REGR_SXX" ...
    "REGR_SYY" ...
    "ROW_NUMBER" ...
    "SQRT" ...
    "STDDEV_POP" ...
    "STDDEV_SAMP" ...
    "SUM" ...
    "UPPER" ...
    "VAR_POP" ...
    "VAR_SAMP" ...
    "CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
    "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
    "CURRENT_PATH" ...
    "CURRENT_ROLE" ...
    "CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
    "CURRENT_USER" ...
    "SESSION_USER" ...
    "SYSTEM_USER" ...
    "USER" ...
    "NEW" ...
    "CASE" ...
    "NEXT" ...
    "CURRENT" ...
    "CURSOR" ...
    "ROW" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "EXISTS" ...
    "(" ...
    "SELECT" ...
    "VALUES" ...
    "TABLE" ...
    "EXPLAIN" ...
    "INSERT" ...
    "UPSERT" ...
    "DELETE" ...
    "UPDATE" ...
    "MERGE" ...
    "CALL" ...
    "SHOW" ...
    "DESCRIBE" ...
    "USE" ...
    "CREATE" ...
    "DROP" ...
    "REFRESH" ...


while parsing SQL query:

from `hive.database`.`demo_table`
^


[Error Id: 9688f8e6-3ce6-42e1-8ef8-94931f511822 on sandbox.hortonworks.com:31010]
]
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=MapR ODBC Driver for Drill DSN
    OdbcErrors=Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I find the solution. Its that Microsoft Power BI do not accept special characters in name of schemas and tables.

Comment: What was the special character? It looks like your table was called demo_table, was _ not an accepted character?

Comment: Yes, _ was not accepted by tool.When I renamed the table as demoTable then its working fine..Thnx